# How can one understand Pugh about outer measures?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading Pugh now and I feel a bit inconvenient about what he says about the outer measure.

He says on page 400 that $m^\ast(A)$ is the infinum of the measure of open sets that contain A. Yes, this is definition.

But then he writes: This infinum is achived by a $G_\delta$-set that contains A.

How can we get that set he denotes as $H_A$.

i don't think I am right if I say that $H_A=\bigcap G$, where $G$ contains $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $m^*(A)<\infty$ first. 
Use the definition of the outer measure, there are open sets $A\subset \cdots \subset U_{n+1}\subset U_n$ such that 
$$
m^*(A)>m (U_n)-1/n
$$
for $n\in \mathbb N$. By monotone class theorem in measure theory, $U_n\subset \cdots \subset U_1$ implies that 
$$
m^*\left (\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty }m(U_n)
$$
Thus 
$$
m^*(A)\geqslant m\left (\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n \right)\tag1
$$ 
Clearly for any $n\in \mathbb N$, there is 
$$
A\subset\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n \quad\text{and}\quad m^*(A)\leqslant m\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n\right)\tag2
$$
With $(1)$ this implies that 
$$
m^*(A)= m\left (\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n \right)
$$ 
It is proved if we let
$$
H_A=G_{\delta}=\bigcap _{n\in \mathbb N}U_n\tag3
$$ 
If $m^*(A)=\infty$, then for each $U_n$, $m(U_n)=\infty$. By $(2)$ we have
$$
m^*(A)= m\left (\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n \right)=\infty
$$ 
and $(3)$ still holds.

Comment: $A$ is not necessarily a Lebesgue measurable set.

Answer (score 2):

If $m^*(A)=\infty$ let $H_A=\mathbb R.$

If $m^*(A)\lt\infty$ then, for each $n\in\mathbb N,$ choose an open set $G_n$ such that $A\subseteq G_n$ and $m(G_n)\lt m^*(A)+\frac1n.$ (I guess the axiom of choice is needed here.) Let $H_A=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}G_n.$

Comment: If $A=\Bbb{R}-[0,1]$, what happen? A set has infinite measure doesn't mean it is $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @hermes I don't think there is any claim that $H_A$ is unique. $\mathbb{R}$ is a set which meets the requirements so we can choose $H_A = \mathbb R$.

Comment: Rigorously speaking, $m(H_A)=\infty$ does not mean it is R. They can be far away. $G_δ$  should be as close to $A$ as possible.

Comment: @hermes Unless $A$ is itself a $G_\delta,$ it is impossible for a $G_\delta$ to be "as close to $A$ as possible"; you can always remove a point and get another $G_\delta.$

Comment: @bof, your comment "it is impossible for a $G_δ$ to be "as close to A as possible" is wrong. Let $A=\bigcup(2n, 2n+1)$ and $U_k=\bigcup(2n-1/k, 2n+1+1/k)$. Clearly $A\subset U_k$ and $A=H_A=\bigcap U_k$. In this example, $U_k$ is only half of $\Bbb{R}$. How can you say $H_A=\Bbb{R}$ even if $m(H_A)=\infty$?

Comment: So even if $m(H_A)=∞$, we can not say $H_A=\Bbb{R}$. As proved in my post, just because $m^*(A)= m\left (\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} U_n \right)=\infty$ holds too.